# ASP.NET MVC concurrent development

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, workflow, concurrent-programming

I am researching the best way of establishing and maintaining a very large intranet site that will be developed concurrently by several developers who will need to make changes to different areas of the site concurrently.

I would like to use ASP.Net MVC for this but I am concerned that it will be very difficult to use this technology as the framework requires that the site be compiled (other than the views) and the deployment process would also seemingly overwrite other changes in the test environment when a developer chose to progress a build from their development machine.

Presently we use an interpreted language that does not force us to build the entire site to deploy individual changes....am I missing something in respect of how compiled frameworks and in particular how ASP.Net MVC works?  Or is it the case that non sequential, fast paced development by several developers will inevitably result in problems when not using interpreted code?

Would PHP make a better choice given the nature of our workflow in the circumstances?

Comment: The language choice should depend on developers, that are available to you. If you are only one, which make the site, then you should choose language, which you most skilled at.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question I'm assuming you are not currently using a version/source control system? If you were to use PHP then yes, you would not need to compile the solution but how would you know if you working from the most up to date version of a given file? Are your development team fighting over the same files?

If you set up a method of version/source control using software such as Subversion (also referred to as SVN) and a proper build deployment methodology (currently I'm using Hudson professionally) whether the deployed solution is compiled or not shouldn't make any difference. It might mean that you cannot open up a file on a live environment to make a quick alteration but if it is a large application and you have several developers randomly pushing changes to a test server, then I can say speaking from experience that you may run into some major problems with the stability of your application using such a workflow.

In summary:

- Get source control
- Get a standard (preferably automated) build deployment process

If you do choose ASP.Net MVC and make use of Visual Studio there are some simple (manual) built in mechanisms for [deployment using Visual Studio](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-your-site-using-visual-studio-cs).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response....yes I had thought to use GIT for version control...using .gitignore to differentiate between source code and compiled files....hopefully that would help us to avoid issues with developers editing the same files and it's probably inevitable that we would need to merge separate changes at some stage.  The issue I think would be more around how developers could deploy their changes to the test environment without overwriting changes that others had already deployed and might be in the middle of testing.....

Comment: If you truly want to avoid toe stepping when testing then the developer should be able to test the changes on their own machine. Sounds like you should stick with PHP if you don't want to make radical changes to your working methodologies. Deploying a new version of code using ASP.Net MVC would temporarily bring the website down and cause things like session state to refresh - which could definitely disrupt another developer mid-test on the same environment. As you said, having a type of code base you could edit in-line (PHP) on a test server would make this way of working easier.